# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' in python logging module

Tags: python, logging

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s'-'%(levelname)s'-'%(message)s')
```

Whenever I try to run this there is an error showing

> TypeError: unsupported operand `type(s) for -: str` and `str`.

Comment: Try `formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')`

Answer (score 0):

You just have an incorrect string. If you want to have `''` for name, level and message, then use:

```py
formatter = logging.Formatter("'%(name)s'-'%(levelname)s'-'%(message)s'")
```

If not then:

```py
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```